# How to update Outlook's To with Word textbox value?

Tags: vba, forms, email, ms-word, textbox

I have a "send feedback" button on a Word template that sends the file via email to a static email address.

I have a textbox named textbox1 where the user enters their email address.

From my understanding I would replace the hard coded email address with the textbox1 variable in the button code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim xOutlookObj As Object
    Dim xEmail As Object
    Dim xDoc As Document
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmail = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xDoc = ActiveDocument
    xDoc.Save
    With xEmail
        .Subject = "Access Request for Governance Library"
        .Body = "Please review and provide feedback."
        .To = EMAIL.EXAMPLE@ABC.com
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Attachments.Add xDoc.FullName
        .Display
    End With
    Set xDoc = Nothing
    Set xEmail = Nothing
    Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Replacing the line with `.To = texbox1` is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Text` property

```
.To = texbox1.Text
```